# El socket se cierra despues de mandar un mensaje

Tags: android, socket, bluetooth

Tengo un chat simple sobre Bluetooth clasico. La implementacion esta en Android/Java.

### Problema

Todo el mecanismo funciona, de hecho permite enviar un mensaje y es recibido correctamente. Lo unico que al mandar un segundo y tercer mensaje ... no se envia, sin embargo, he visto que el log muestra el siguiente error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
    getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Segun lo que entiendo es que el socket queda de algun modo inactivo y decide cerrar la comunicacion del Input.

### Codigo

El codigo que tengo para enviar los mensajes es el siguiente:

Este metodo sirve para obtener los elementos del chat, leer lo que esta en un `EditText` que es el mensaje que voy a enviar y al hacer click sobre el boton de enviar lo transmitira sobre socket

```
  private void init(){
    listMainchat = findViewById(R.id.lista_conversacion);
    edCreateMessage = findViewById(R.id.mensaje_entrada);
    btnSendMessage = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_msg);

//  Adaptador para poder indrucir elementos a la lista de la conmversacion
    adapterMainChat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.message_layout);
    listMainchat.setAdapter(adapterMainChat);

    btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String message = edCreateMessage.getText().toString();
        if(!message.isEmpty()){
          edCreateMessage.setText(null);
          chatUtils.write(message.getBytes());
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Este mensaje se recibe por el siguiente metodo :
Que crea un Thread que gestiona la conexion ya establecida entre ambos dispositivos

```
 public void write(byte[] buffer){
    ConnectedThread conThread;
    synchronized (this){
      if(state != STATE_CONNECTED){
        return;
      }
      conThread= connectedThread;
    }
    conThread.write(buffer);
  }
```

```
   public void write(byte[] buffer){
      try {
        outputStream.write(buffer);
        handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE,-1,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
      }catch (IOException e){}
    }
```

### Edit

Buscando en los Logs he encontrado este mensaje en un `catch`

```
E/Connect->Run: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

Que sale del constructor del Thread de la conexion del socket:

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread{

    private final BluetoothSocket socket;
    private final BluetoothDevice device;
//  Constructor del Thread, recibimos un device
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device){
//  creamos un socket para el dispositivo remoto a travez de Bluetooth clasico (BD/EDR)
      this.device = device;
      BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
      try{
        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(APP_UUID);
      }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Connect->constructor", e.toString());
      }
      socket = tmp;
    }

    public void run (){
//  Intentamos conectar al socket del dispositivo remoto
      try{
        socket.connect();
      }catch (IOException e_){
        Log.e("Connect->Run", e_.toString());
        try{
          Log.d("La ejecucion del trhead ha sido interrumpida",", vamos a cerrar el socket");
          socket.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
          Log.e("Connect->CloseSocket", e.toString());
        }
        connectionFailed();
        return;
      }

      synchronized (ChatUtils.this){
        connectThread = null;
      }
//    Terminamos de conectar y notificamos al sistema de que estamos conectados
      connected(socket,device);
    }


    public void cancel(){
      try {
        socket.close();
      }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("Connect->Cancel", e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: El mensaje que agregas no indica un error, te sugiero buscar el texto "Caused by", saludos.

Comment: si, tienes razon ahora lo edito, tiene que ver con un error con el socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final trasteando resulta que el fallo no estaba en el metodo de write, sino en el de read, ya que, tal y como estan implentados los sockets solo estan preparados para escuchar por un unico envio dentro del `InputStream`. Para solucionar esto hay que poner el metodo en bucle, de esta forma esta siempre escuchando, hasta que un evento ocurra, como que se cierre el socket o que haya una excepcion (o dejarlo indefinido con un `while(true)`XDD )